# Cardinality of finite subsets in $X$, where $\mid X \mid = \kappa \ge \aleph_0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Trying to show that if $X$ is of cardinality $\kappa \geq \aleph_0$ then the following sets are of cardinality $\kappa$

1. The set of finite sequences of elements of $X$,
2. the set of those functions that map a finite subset of $X$ into $X$.

Feedback? Thoughts?

1. The set of sequences of elements of $X$ of length $k=1,2,3,...$ (some finite sequence) is of cardinality $|X|^k= \kappa^k$. By the Fundamental Theorem on Cardinal Arithmetics, $\kappa^k = \kappa$, thus $\mid X \mid ^k = \kappa$. Now the set of all finite sequence in $X$ is $X^{<\omega} = \bigcup_{k < \omega} X^k$ and  its cardinality is bounded by $\aleph_0 \cdot \sup_{k < \omega} \mid X^k \mid = \aleph_0 \cdot \kappa = \kappa$.
2. The set of those functions that map a finite subset $A$ of $X$ into $X$ is of cardinality $|X|^{|A|}$ . We already proved that $|X|^{|A|}=|X|=\kappa$ . Let $[X]^{<\omega}$ be the set of all finite $A \subseteq X$. Its cardinality is at most $\mid X^{<\omega} \mid = \kappa$ and thus there are $\mid \bigcup_{A \in [X]^{<\omega}} \mid X \mid^{\mid A \mid} \le \mid [X]^{< \omega} \mid \cdot \sup_{A \in [X]^{<\omega}} \mid X \mid ^{\mid A \mid } = \kappa \cdot \kappa = \kappa$ many functions from finite subsets $A \subseteq X$ into $X$.

Comment: In your argument, you often wrote $k$ where you meant to write $\kappa$ and your argument was a bit lacking. The general approach was sound and after some improvements I made, it's now a valid proof of the above claims. Good job!